# how to show full showModalBottomSheet when open keyboard

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I used `isScrollControlled: true` and `SingleChildScrollView` widget..when open keyboard how to open full sheet?

```
  onPressed: () {
                              showModalBottomSheet(
                                  context: context,
                                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                    return BottomSheet(
                                        camera: camera,
                                      subPost: widget.subPost
                                    );
                                  },isScrollControlled: true);
                            },
```

BottomSheet class

```
class _BottomSheetState extends State<BottomSheet> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return
      SingleChildScrollView(
      child:
      Container(
        child: Padding(
          padding:
          EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
          child: Column(
```

**My output**

[image: my output]

**I need like this**
[image: I need like this]

Answer (score 0):

> your screen is not scrolling, because your bottom sheet is not
> scrollable.

**Try below code :**

```
 showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      isScrollControlled: true,
...
```